# Proving special case where partial derivatives existing implies differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

I am trying to prove a statement which says if you have a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^m}$ and $\partial f_i/\partial x$ exists for $i = 1, \dots, m$ then $Df$ exists.

I was wondering if I could get some comments on my proposed proof, I can pretty much only use the definition of the derivative and partial derivative?

We can write $f(x) = (f_1(x), f_2(x), \dots , f_m(x))$ where each $f_i : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then since $\partial f_i/ \partial x$ exists we know

$$\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x}(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = Df_i(x)$$

since $f_i$ goes from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $Df_i = \partial f_i / \partial x$, which means

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{|f_i(x) - f_i(x_0) - Df_i(x_0)(x-x_0)|}{|x-x_0|} = 0$$

by definition of derivative. Let

$$Df = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x} \end{pmatrix}$$

Then we have

$$\left|\left|\frac{f(x) - f(x_0) -Df(x_0)(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}\right|\right| \leq \sum_{i=1}^m \left|\frac{f_i(x) - f_i(x_0)-Df_i(x_0)(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}\right| \to 0, x \to x_0$$

Hence,

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\left|\left|\frac{f(x) - f(x_0) -Df(x_0)(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}\right| \right| = 0$$

and $Df$ satisfies the definition of the derivative.

Comment: I don't think those would usually be called  _partial_ derivatives since you only have one input variable.

Comment: Haha true, I guess it would be better to say if the derivatives of the component functions exist?